# JavaScript: Simple SoundCloud API example for Streaming won't work properly with Safari

Tags: javascript, api, safari, streaming, soundcloud

I'm quite frustrated with a simple soundcloud api streaming example I'm working on for couple of days know. It basically just chooses randomly a SC-url and prints out a volume information. I'm using the audiostreamsource.js library by Gregg Tavares for creating the audiocontext and the p5.js for creating a paragraph.
That's it... 
It works perfectly fine on Fireforx/Chrome. But for some reason it only works in Safari when I refresh the page. Sometime it even crashes with Safari. :( I think I'm  just not experienced enough to get behind that problem. I really tried to solve it from every possible angle. Now I'm stuck.... :(

You can see my little example here: http://christianlosert.com/test/01/
EDIT: To see the problem you have to past the link above into a new browser tab. Then you'll see that after a couple of milliseconds the streaming aborts in Safari.

Can anybody see my mistake?

PS: With the help of Gregg Tavares I tried to create an streaming example without the audiostreamsource.js/p5.js library to make sure the bug is on my side of the code. Curiously this example works ONLY with Safari (not Firefox/Chrome): http://christianlosert.com/test/greg/

I really have absolutely no clue what's going on here

Answer (score 1):

The soundcloud 3.0 library does not work with Safari. See

[soundcloud's 2.0 sdk works but 3.0 does not as of Oct 29th, 2015](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33431256/soundclouds-2-0-sdk-works-but-3-0-does-not-as-of-oct-29th-2015)

You can either

1. use the soundcloud 2.0 library (problem: it initializes flash even if it doesn't use it)
2. Just make the soundcloud API request on your own using some XHR code

   Basically you make an XHR request to

   ```
   https://api.soundcloud.com/resolve?url=<musicUrl>&client_id=<yourclientid>&format=json&_status_code[302]=200
   ```

   note: you need to call `encodeURIComponent` on `<musicUrl>` and possibly on `_staus_code[302]`

   If the result has a status of 302 then follow the location

   ```
   var result = JSON.parse(resultString);
   if (result.status.substr(0, 3) === "302" && result.location) {

      do XHR on result.location

   else

      use result as normal
   ```