# Soundcloud API : not working on Safari

Tags: javascript, safari, soundcloud

I'm using the Soundcloud API on a website to get and stream tracks. I'm using the methods "resolve" and "stream" :

```
SC.get('/resolve', { url: url }, function(track) {
   SC.stream('/tracks/' + track.id, function(sound) {
     sound.play();
   });
});
```

It works well on all major browsers, except Safari, which returns the several errors :

```
[Error] XMLHttpRequest cannot load *url* Request header field Accept-Encoding is not allowed by Access-Control-Allow-Headers.
```

I've checked online and it seems I'm not the only one dealing with this issue ([example](https://github.com/soundcloud/soundcloud-javascript/issues/27)), but I haven't seen any solutions (except a possible proxy but I would rather not use one). Any ideas?

Thanks!

Comment: This is a duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33431256/soundclouds-2-0-sdk-works-but-3-0-does-not-as-of-oct-29th-2015